# umount filesystem exported via nfs: target is busy

Tags: centos, nfs

CentOS 7.5.1804

I cannot unount filesystem, that was exported via nfs.
On nfsv4 client was connected in the past.

I removed all references from /etc/exports.
exportfs and /proc/fs/nfsd/exports shows that mount directory is not exported anymore.
I checked mount point with lsof (empty list) and fuser -mv:

```
[root@host ~]# fuser -mv /storage/nfs/test
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/storage/nfs/test:  root     kernel mount /storage/nfs/test
```

Is there any other way to check what is blocking umount?

Comment: Try to reload nfs-server, sometimes it need a restart. Also check for samba config if any.

Answer (score 0):

`lsof /storage/nfs/test`

Also, update your server. Current is CentOS 7.9